# Set world origin to cursor - how to?

Tags: world, origin

How can I set the world origin to the 3D cursor?

I created a quite complex animation with many objects and somehow moved far off the world origin. Now I would like to have to whole animation centered around the world origin again. I don`t want to (i.e. don´t know how to efficiently) move all the keyframe locations closer to the world origin.

Comment: Hello, have you tried using Delta transforms ? If all your objects are offset by the same value, you can add the same delta transform to all of them. It won't affect the regular keyframes

Comment: You can also try to parent everything to an empty and then moving the empty to the origin. It can be tricky if the scene is complex and already has many small objects parented to other objects, but if it's a relatively simple set up it usually does the trick.